# How to serve the same value for multiple consumers from single LinkedBlockingQueue in java

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, producer-consumer

The producer thread will insert something (record) into the queue. I have 4 other threads which will consume the record from that queue and it will proceed some other process with that record. Here my question is: If the first thread reads the value from queue then it will be removed from queue and it is not available for other threads. But I need that record for remaining 3 threads. How can I supply the same record to all 4 consumer threads.

Comment: Is it always like this? Does each task have to be run by all consumers? Why is that? It doesn't really make sense to me. Or are the consumers different implementations and do different things with the record?

Comment: yes. Each consumer will do different work with that record, but all the consumers should get the record from same queue..
Is it possible to do like this?

Comment: Well, I'd expect workers to all do the same. But I guess you have 4 independent things to do with same data, so why not have 4 queues?

Comment: Yes. In my current code structure I have 4 different queues and Its working fine, but to restrict the memory usage I advised to have one common queue for all 4 tasks.